# ECommandService Discouraged access

Tags: java, osgi, eclipse-rcp, e4

I'm trying to inject the ECommandService into a Part of my application, and I've added the plugin *org.eclipse.e4.core.commands;bundle-version="0.10.2"* to the dependencies of my application (plugin.xml), but when I declare the

```
@Inject private ECommandService commandService;
```

I'm getting a warning saying:

```
Discouraged access: The type ECommandService is not accessible due to 
restriction on required library C:\Data\andrelop\transnet\eclipse-
kepler\plugins\org.eclipse.e4.core.commands_0.10.2.v20130515-1857.jar
```

Is this normal or Am I adding the wrong dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal for a number of e4 APIs. These APIs have not yet been finalized so they are left 'discouraged' - but you have to use them for e4 applications. There is a chance that they may change in future Eclipse releases.

You can turn off the warning in `Preferences > Java > Compiler > Errors/Warning` in the `Deprecated and restricted API` section change `Discouraged reference (access rules)` to `ignore`. Or you can use `@SuppressWarning("restriction")` on your class.

Eclipse bug [412373](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=412373) will list the APIs which will finalized in Eclipse 4.4 (Luna), but currently it is empty. Some e4 APIs were finalized when 4.3 was released.